# Set HTTPClient encoding on WP8.1

Tags: json, character-encoding, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient

I'm porting my WP8 app to WP8.1, it's almost ready, except a code that uses WebClient to get JSON data.
In WP8.1 I cant use WebClient anymore, so I tried using HTTPClient, with no success.
The problem here is that I need to set the encoding to UTF-8, but I don't figured out a way to do that.

In WP8 the code looks like that:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
```

But HTTPClient doesn't have the Encoding property.
Anyone knows a way to set this on HTTPClient?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the data as a byte array, and then decode it using UTF-8 manually:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
    htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: This is used to return a string, so it cannot be async. It's a good solution to create an async method to get the bytes or you know a better solution?
`public static string RequestRaw(string url) { string htmlCode = ""; using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) { byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url); htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); } return htmlCode; }`

Comment: If you don't want it to be async, you can use: `byte[] data = client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri).Result;` but since it's a web request it makes sense for it to be async

Comment: Ok, I transformed it in a `Task<string>`. Thanks for the help.